# Text Mining sql schema files

Tags: java, sql, text-mining

I have a collection of big sql files. From those Files I want to keep only the "CREATE TABLE" and "Alter table add constraint Foreign Key" statements. Is There a toll I can use to mine those two regular expressions? I know that I could use grep but I don't have linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a small Java program to obtain only such sentences. e.g.:

```
String input = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("file.sql")), "UTF-8");
String regex = "(?i)((create table|alter table add constraint foreign key)[^;]+;)"
        .replace(" ", "\\s+");
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Comment: this is the first I've seen such a way to parse regular expressions thank you for your insightful answer

Comment: sorry to bother you but I made a mistake. The alter table statement is 
ALTER TABLE (String) ADD CONSTRAINT (String) FOREIGN KEY (String)

Comment: Try with `String regex = "(?i)((create|alter)\\s+table[^;]+;)";`

Answer (score -1):

The below code will return you the whole line you can do  substring or something as per your requirement.

```
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;

public class Test extends BufferedReader {
  String pattern;

  public Test(Reader in, String pattern) {
    super(in);
    this.pattern = pattern;
  }

  public final String readLine() throws IOException {
    String line;
    do {
      line = super.readLine();
    } while ((line != null) && line.indexOf(pattern) == -1);
    return line;
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
      Test in = new Test(new FileReader("test.txt"), "emement2");
      String line;
      while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(line);
      in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.err.println(e);
    }
  }
}
```